# SQL Server - How to check for duplicates within result set most efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am writing a stored procedure that more or less runs a 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE' statement on a table I want to return the results of the query to the user but to check if there are any duplicates within the result of the query. If there are, I'd like to throw an error. Otherwise, the result set should be returned.

**To summarise, code should:**

1. SELECT from a table
2. Check for duplicates in the result of that SELECT query and throw an error if any are found.
3. If none are found, return the result set.

**My current thought is that I need to do something like:**

1. Create a table variable with a unique constraint on the relevant columns
2. Insert into the table variable from the 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE'
3. If there are duplicates, the constraint will be violated and I'll handle that in a catch clause
4. If there are no duplicates, my code will continue and 'SELECT * FROM @TableVariable'

A possible alternative might be CTEs, but I'm not sure.

**My question is whether this is the correct approach for this problem.**

Sub-questions:

1. Is there a better way of doing this?
2. Will the above not work for some reason?
3. Am I likely to see a significant slowing down in my query because I am doing SELECT twice? Or is the Table variable stored in such a way that it does not 'cost' very much to do the second SELECT?

Comment: This depends on the amount of data you have to deal with.  How large is the result set?  How many columns need to be unique?

Comment: I can't see a better way based on what you have said, although the best solution would really be to [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Write your query and test it, check if it works as you expect, check how quickly it runs. Then if it doesn't run as fast as you would want, then you can try other methods, and see if they are faster. This will provide much more insight than anyone else will be able to based on the information you have provided.

Comment: As Gareth said, it's not such a bad idea, just if you are using transactions and there are some operations before check duplication, raising error must handle rolling back the transaction, so sometimes it cost a fortune and it's better to validate data before going in transactions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The results set may get up to the millions of rows but not likely to go past that. The number of columns to be unique is actually not static - could be from 1 up to 7 or so

Comment: You could use a temp table with unique constraint instead of a table variable. Since table variables are not the most performant.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts - do you think a temp table would be more efficient here?

Comment: @MosheSteinberg read [this](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/table-variables/) unless you are using SQL Server 2019, witch has some improvements for table variables?

Comment: While your idea will work it will introduce latency to your queries. If your old queries contained no aggregation elements then they could be streaming rows back to the connecting client while gathering the remaining results. With your proposal the buffering table would have to be completely filled before the first row could be returned to the client. Depending on your application this may not matter, but it is something that should be considered.